# extend base.html problem

Tags: django, templates, extends

I'm getting the following error:

```
Template error

In template /home/mo/python/django/templates/yoga/index.html, error at line 1
Caught TemplateDoesNotExist while rendering: base.html
1 {% extends "base.html" %}
2 
3 {% block main %}
4     <p>{{ page.title }}</p>
5     <p>{{ page.info}}</p>
6     <a href="method/">Method</a>
7 {% endblock %}
8
```

this is my base.html file, which is located at the same place as index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <div style="width:50%; marginleft:25%;">
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
```

what exactly is going on here? should the base.html file be located somewhere else?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"At the same place" as `yoga/index.html` means that the template is actually `yoga/base.html`.

Answer (score 18):

Assuming TEMPLATE_DIRS contains `/home/mo/python/django/templates/`, without the `.../yoga/`, so you need to:

move `base.html` into `/home/mo/python/django/templates/`

OR

write `{% extends "yoga/base.html" %}` in your template

Comment: Of the two fix options, I think best practice would be to put `base.html` in /home/mo/python/django/templates/ and leave your `extends` reference to it unchanged. That will keep the app modular. Another site you build can chose to use your app's `base.html` or ovrerride it and force your app to take on the new header/footer/style of the new site. I think this is how Pinax does themes, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Is base.html in a directory in the TEMPLATE_DIRS list in your settings file?

Answer (score 1):

**Base.html** file must be located at the base of templates folder to use ' base.html ' , if located in another folder such as: `templates / home / base.html` , then you must specify the path using

```
{ % Extends ' home / base.html '% }
```

Comment: Does your answer add anything more to it than [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3066407/3375713) and [Evgecyn's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3067380/3375713) answers? I doubt it does.